# How to implement pull to refresh in UITableviewcontroller in Tabbased application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, pull-to-refresh

I am working on a project which contains both applications i.e Navigation and Tab based application. There I used tableview to show some titles with there images. I want to implement pull to refresh mechanism in it. I have the code of that and it is working fine in navigation based application. But, when I tried the same code in my project it is not showing there.

There might be some issues of views which I m not able to resolve. So can anybody provide me some sample code or tutorial to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look here
http://github.com/leah/PullToRefresh
or
http://github.com/enormego/EGOTableViewPullRefresh.

Two projects providing "pull to refresh" components.